# Writing fantasy novel and reintroducing a character

Tags: characters, book, perspective

When writing a book, when I introduce a character to the audience do I have to reintroduce them again if it's in a different character's point of view?

Answer (score 3):

Typically yes, but you can do this much more briefly. The reader is already familiar with the character, and in a way some of the introduction can happen "off screen". Presume Mike and Alice meet in a previous scene, but Jake hasn't met Alice yet. Presume we already know Alice is exceptionally beautiful and knows it, she is a model. Mike is helping her with a problem (the point of the plot), and he takes her to recruit Jake.

So we see this scene from Jake's POV. And eventually, Jake and Alice end up together, so we don't want Alice too creeped out by Jake.

> Jake saw Mike and Alice enter the bar together, and walk toward him, his eyes widened.

> Mike said, "Hey Jake. This is Alice."

> Jake and Alice shake hands. He doesn't let go, his eyes locked on hers. Jake said, "Alice. Alice."

> Alice said, "Jake Jake! Are we going to hold hands all night? I had other plans for this hand."

> Jake laughs, breaks eye contact. "Oh my god, you're funny too!"

When you write, your scene is always to assist the **reader's** imagination.

Since the reader is already familiar with Alice, their imagination of her is pre-loaded. You don't need to describe her again.

You are writing from Jake's POV, but still **for** the reader, not for Jake. So don't be redundant. Jake's reaction to Alice is sufficient, the reader gets it.

You don't have to write "Jake thinks she beautiful," as the maxim goes, "show don't tell". In this case, that means you *show* us Jake's reaction, that is what tells us how he feels upon meeting Alice for the first time.

And of course, Alice herself is long accustomed to reactions like Jake's: she is professionally beautiful, after all. So she reacts with humor to avoid any awkwardness.

But notice we don't describe Alice at all, we just show Jake's reaction to her.

Comment: Also note that many readers (or at least me) enjoy seeing new characters react to the existing characters that they already know and love.  This type of introduction can be a quite entertaining if done properly.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus +1, agreed 100%. It is a good way in a sequel to remind readers of characteristics of your existing characters, through the eyes of a new character they are learning about.

Answer (score 1):

I second @Amadeus' opinion that second introduction should be much shorter.

However, you can benefit from providing a look from a different perspective, a "second opinion" of sorts. Borrowing form @Amadeus' example, Mike would give his view of Alice first, and while this can be a fair and objective view, Mike can certainly miss a lot of details. Next thing, Jake would see Alice and see all those details that Jake had missed. The reader would have a much more complete (and potentially complex) picture from those two descriptions. Mike might not see any reasons to like Alice too much, but from Jake point of view Alice may seem perfect.

You also may want to play those two viewpoints against each other, either making the reader fall in love with Alice too, or make it look like poor Jake is being blinded by his passion.

Just don't leave too much time between providing two views. Readers' mental picture is getting formed rather quickly, and waiting for two chapters after the first introduction to mention that Alice actually has blue eyes and red hair may not sit well with reader's imagination.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to bore your reader is by repeating information they already know. So if that reintroduction does not add any new information, then cut it.

But nevertheless, reintroducing a character again from the viewpoint of a different character can be useful if that reintroduction is notably different. This can be used to create contrast in how different characters perceive this person.

The description of character A from the perspective of B might be:

> "a beautiful and confident bachelor, whose dreamy eyes make every woman swoon".

But the same character described from the perspective of character C might be:

> "a vain and self-centered jerk, whose lecherous gaze makes every woman uncomfortable".

This tells the reader as much about B and C as it tells them about A. And it shows (without telling) that A is a multi-faceted character who polarizes the characters in the narrative and might polarize the readership. So the reader is invited to form their own opinion on this character by following the rest of the story.

Comment: I agree. The advantage of multiple points of view is the ability to cast the same characters and events in different narrative lighting, which can add nuance, mystery (if they conflict), or humor to your story depending on how you use these different points of view.